# SIgnalR iOS Client returning null for connectionId and protocol version

Tags: ios, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to integrate an iOS app of mine to work with a MVC3 (framework 4) SignalR program that we have set up on a development server on our local network. The website that has been created for this works fine throughout our network.

However when trying to use the SignalR iOS Client it gives the following error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Incompatible Protocol Version'
```

After using some NSLog() within the SRConnection.m I figured out that when the app is negotiating it does so successfully but doesn't get a connectionId or protocol version, these return null

```
    negotiation was successful NegotiationResponse: ConnectionId=(null) Url=/signalr/signalr ProtocolVersion=(null)
```

I'm setting up the connection in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function of the appDelegate. This is how I'm setting up the connection :

```
    SRHubConnection *connection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:
                               @"http://mark-dev"];
    myHub = [connection createProxy:@"ChatHub"];
    [connection start];
```

I've also had a look at the connection logs on the server. It's receiving the request and returning a status code of 200 each time..

The connection code I'm using I got for this was off http://chrisrisner.com/iOS-and-Windows-Azure-Communication-using-SignalR..

I have tried using the url and hub name in the example and that negotiates okay with a connectionId and protocol version which looks like this:

```
    negotiation was successful NegotiationResponse: ConnectionId=48a6fcca-429f-4d3e-b374-8f10d6889fe0 Url=/signalr/signalr ProtocolVersion=1.0
```

This is also all in the iPad Simulator on iOS sdk6 with a deployment target of iOS 5.1

Any help on this would be great

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that although i had included the `SignalR` reference for somereason the NuGet didn't download `SignalR.Hosting.AspNet` and `SignalR.Hosting.Common` and after adding these manually it worked fine.

The incomplete download must have been a fluke, as I tried it on another project and it downloaded fully.

Comment: can u kindly upload the sample project somwhere ? I have the same issue.